# How to add a unique ID on date by adding a table row

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i add a unique ID to the date. Basically I want to add a unique ID on date to be unique, and by clicking the add row button of the table it create a new record then will generate a new date that contains with new unique ID.

So basically the actual result is that by clicking the add row button it will create another row the contains with new dates. If there is anyone could help it really much appreciated.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="adj_table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="tbl_adj">
        <td>
            <div class="form-group input-group">                 
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="adj_date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left;">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm" onclick="addTableRows()">Add Row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

this is my function in adding the row.

```
function addTableRows(){
    var count = $('#adj_table >tbody >tr').length;
    var count_length = count + 1;

        var newRow = $("<tr id='tr_"+count_length+"' class='tbl_adj'>");
        var column = "";

        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';
        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';
        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';

        newRow.append(column);
        $("#adj_table").append(newRow);
}
```

This is my date, im using daterangepicker.

```
$('#adj_date').daterangepicker({ singleDatePicker: true, locale: { format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}});
```

So basically the actual result is that by clicking the addrow button it will create another row the contains with new dates. If there is anyone could help it really much appreciated.

Comment: An ID can only be unique in the context of all the other IDs you have created. You could, for instance, use the `count_length` variable as an unique ID. It will always be different from the other IDs.

Comment: so how do I do that? do you have recommendation?

Comment: No, can't recommend anything. That's why I made it a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: What is the actual result of what you have done?

Because it seems okay as you are using tr_ + the current length as the id

You should have something like tr_1 for the first row, tr_2 for the next and so on except that you didn't close your tr tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="adj_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tbl_adj">
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group input-group">                 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm adj_date" id="adj_date1">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left;">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm" onclick="addTableRows()">Add Row</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function addTableRows(){
        var count = $('#adj_table >tbody >tr').length;
        var count_length = count + 1;

            var newRow = $("<tr id='tr_"+count_length+"' class='tbl_adj'>");
            var column = "";


            //generate random date between start_date and end_date
            var randomDate1 = randomDate(new Date(2019, 0, 1), new Date());  

            //generate  random date without range
            //var randomDate1 = moment(new Date(+(new Date()) - Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000))).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            var randomDate2 = moment(new Date(+(new Date()) - Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000))).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            var randomDate3 = moment(new Date(+(new Date()) - Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000))).format('MM/DD/YYYY');


            column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm adj_date" value="' + randomDate1 +'"></td>';
            column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm adj_date" value="' + randomDate2 +'"></td>';
            column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm adj_date" value="' + randomDate3 +'"></td>';

            newRow.append(column);
            $("#adj_table").append(newRow);
    }

    $('.adj_date').daterangepicker({ singleDatePicker: true, locale: { format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}});

    $('body').on('focus',".adj_date", function(){
        $(this).daterangepicker({ singleDatePicker: true, locale: { format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}});
    });

    //generate random date between start_date and end_date
    function randomDate(start, end) {
        return moment(new Date(+(start.getTime()) - Math.floor(Math.random()* (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) ))).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try closing your tr tag before appending the columns (td's) to it

```
    function addTableRows(){
    var count = $('#adj_table >tbody >tr').length;
    var count_length = count + 1;

        var newRow = $("<tr id='tr_"+count_length+"' class='tbl_adj'></tr>");
        var column = "";

        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';
        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';
        column += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></td>';

        newRow.append(column);
        $("#adj_table").append(newRow);
}
```